# Java: How to recognize a specific string

Tags: java, string, swing, keyevent

I'm making a simple chat through Swing, and having some issues.

I'm trying to make my client send a private message to another user when it get's input "/w anotheruserid". It's not about the EventHandler, but how to recognize the string. The event handler is to be like the one below.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
if(textField.getText().equals("/w ")){

     }
}
```

How should I make it to get additional string input such as another user's id?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the user id itself? You could try breaking down the input into pieces and verifying each piece is what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`startsWith`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if(textField.getText().startsWith("/w ")){
}
```

That way you can simply [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) the text and exclude the `/w` part to use it as `/w something`.

```
String message = textField.getText().substring(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use regular expression for this or can use String substring function to get the first two characters and then can match it with "/w".

Answer (score 1):

```
if(textField.getText().equals("/w ")){
```

This condition is true only if the text in textField is "`/w`";

You can use `if(textField.getText().startsWith("/w "))` instead.

And then you can remove the first 3 characters, including '/', 'w' and Space ' ', to populate another user id.

Using `StringValue.substring(3)`;

An example is as follows:

```
String text = "/w anotheruserid";

    System.out.printf("Before populating anotheruserid==>%s\n", text);
    if (text.startsWith("/w ")) {
        text = text.substring(3);

        /*
         * Remove the first 3 characters, including '/' ,'w' and ' ')
         */

        System.out.printf("After  Populating anotheruserid==>%s\n", text);
    }
```

**Output in Console:**

```
Before populating anotheruserid==>/w anotheruserid
After  Populating anotheruserid==>anotheruserid
```